# Sending ("test", 1.0d) yields in a Java 8 compilation error, ambiguous method call xMethod(String,double...) vs xMethod(String,Object...)

Tags: java, overloading, ambiguous

Java 8 is complaining that the following method call is ambiguous:

```
reference to overloadedMethod is ambiguous
both method overloadedMethod(java.lang.String,double...) in XTest and 
     method overloadedMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...) in XTest match
```

```
    @Test
    public void testUnboxing() {
        Double test = new Double(1.0);
        this.overloadedMethod("Hola" , test);
        this.overloadedMethod("Hola" , 1.01d);

    }

    private void overloadedMethod(String test, double... args){
        System.out.println("Method 1");

    }

    private void overloadedMethod(String test, Object... args){
        System.out.println("Method 2");

    }
```

The only way I managed to compile this code is by adding a null at the end of the parameter list, which outputs Method 2.

```
this.overloadedMethod("Hola" , 1.01d, null);
```

There is nothing in the  [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) that I could find that explains this behavior.  Could I, in my infinite and unmatched wisdom, missed something? Might this be a bug in Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

The triple-dots (varargs) are the crucial aspect here. Without them, the `Object` version just wins. However, WITH varargs, it's ambiguous, even if you 'upgrade' the `Object...` variant to `Double...` instead. ecj agrees, which usually indicates they are both following spec.

And so it is; the relevant section is all 3 bits of [JLS 15.12.2.2 through JLS 15.12.2.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2).

Whilst there is the 'strict' and then the 'loose' application which is why the Object version wins without the varargs, once you dive to the third level (variable arity is JLS-ese for 'varargs', those triple dots), there is no such separation, therefore, these method sigs both 'fit' at the 15.12.2.4 level. And thus, this is ambiguous.

---

Heh, whilst experimenting, I found a java bug. This code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 5.0;
        test(d);
    }
    public void test(Double d) { System.out.println("D"); }
    public void test(double d) { System.out.println("d"); }
```

does not compile, producing the error 'reference to test is ambiguous'. This error is doubly erroneous. It does not highlight the actual error in this code (which is that the test methods are instance methods, they cannot be invoked from a static context), and does indicate that this invocation is ambiguous which it is not; make the test methods static and the code compiles; the lowercase-d variant wins.

As expected, ecj (eclipse's compiler) does not suffer from this bug and reports the right error. It tends to do better at following spec than javac.

Comment: So, does this mean that you will never be able to overload a method that takes Object... o as parameter?

Comment: pretty much, yeah.